# Need help to find where I was wrong while solving for inequality

Tags: inequality

Here is inequality and we should solve for n:
$$c_1n^2 - 2c_1n + c_1 + c_0n \le c_1n^2$$

The answer should be $n \ge \frac{c_1}{2c_1 - c_0}$

Here is my solution (btw, my way of solving inequality is slow and inefficient, I will be thankful if you show me the way where I did redundant steps and I could "see" solution faster):

$$n(c_1n - 2c_1 + c_0) + c_1 \le c_1n^2 - c_1 $$
$$\frac{n(c_1n - 2c_1 + c_0)}{n} \le \frac{c_1n^2 - c_1}{n}$$
$$c_1n - 2c_1 + c_0 \le \frac{c_1n^2 - c_1}{n} $$
$$-2c_1 + c_0 \le \frac{c_1n^2-c_1}{n} - c_1n$$
$$-2c_1 + c_0 \le \frac{c_1n^2 - c_1 - c_1n^2}{n}$$
$$-2c_1 + c_0 *\frac{1}{c_1} \le \frac{c_1(n^2-1-n^2)}{n}  *\frac{1}{c_1}$$
$$ \frac{-2c_1 + c_0}{c_1} \le \frac{-1}{n}$$
$$ \frac{2c_1 - c_0}{c_1} \ge \frac{1}{n}$$

$$ \frac{c_1}{2c_1 - c_0} \le n$$

Thus, $$n > \frac{c_1}{2c_1 - c_0}$$

So, I got > instead of $\ge$. Where was I wrong?

Thank you

Comment: I guess the RHS of the inequality is wrong, @UserMoon. Otherwise, you can subtract from both members $c_1n^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$c_1n^2-2c_1n+c_1+c_0n\leq c_1n$$
$$\iff (-2c_1+c_0)n+c_1\leq 0$$
$$\iff (c_0-2c_1)n\leq -c_1$$

Then you have three cases, either $2c_1 > c_0$ or $2c_1<c_0$ or $2c_1=c_0$ :

- if $2c_1 > c_0$ :
  $$\iff n \geq -\frac{c_1}{c_0-2c_1} \iff n \geq \frac{c_1}{2c_1 - c_0}$$
- if $2c_1 < c_0$ :
  $$\iff n \leq -\frac{c_1}{c_0-2c_1} \iff n \leq \frac{c_1}{2c_1 - c_0}$$
- if $2c_1 = c_0$ :
  $$\iff 0 \leq -c_1$$